# Why was Thor's quinjet password 'Point Break'?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, thor-marvel, thor-ragnarok

When Thor tries to activate the quinjet in Thor Ragnarok, he tries using a few different passwords for the voice activation system. "Thor", "Son of Odin", and "Strongest Avenger".

The actual quinjet password ends up being "Point Break". Thor then vents his frustration with Tony Stark, as if it were a personal insult.

Why was Thor's quinjet password "Point Break"? Is it a reference to something?

Comment: http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0102685/

Answer (score 117, accepted):

This is a back-reference to [the first Avengers film](http://www.imsdb.com/scripts/Avengers,-The-(2012).html).

> **TONY** (CONT'D): (TO THOR)  *No hard feelings, **Point Break.** You've got a mean swing. (referring to the Iridium) Also, it means the
>   portal can open as wide, and stay open as long, as Loki  wants.*

The idea being that Thor looks like Patrick Swayze's character [Bodhi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point_Break) in the [film of the same name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point_Break).

[image: Thor vs Bodhi]

Comment: Note that in the original Marvel series, Thor would often be nicknamed by his partners, including Iron Man, as "Goldilocks".

Answer (score 46):

### It’s Tony’s nickname for Thor

According to an [Screen Rant article](https://screenrant.com/thor-ragnarok-things-you-completely-missed-references-easter-eggs-hidden/):

> When Thor enters the Quinjet he has a hard time gaining access to its
>   controls. The ship asks for voice recognition input and he uses many
>   different names including, “Thor,” “Thor, Son of Odin,” “God of
>   Thunder,” and “Strongest Avenger.” However, the name that ultimately
>   gains him access is “Point Break.”
>
> Point Break is the name Tony Stark gave Thor in the first Avengers
>   film because of his resemblance to Patrick Swayze in the 1991 film,
>   Point Break. In this surfer-robber ’90s movie, Swayze sports long
>   luscious blonde hair, much like the God of Thunder’s flowing locks,
>   and Stark is more than happy to point this out from time to time.

Thor doesn’t like this nickname (it’s got an edge of mockery), so naturally he’d be upset. Plus, Tony came up with it while criticizing Thor:

> **TONY (to Thor):** It’s a stabilizing agent.
>
> **(to Coulson):** I’ll fly you there. Keep the love alive. Means the portal won’t collapse on itself, like it did at SHIELD.
>
> **(to Thor):** No hard feelings, Point Break. You’ve got a mean swing.